# Cant make Alamofire work

Tags: alamofire, xcode8, swift2

I'm trying to start a project using Alamofire with xCode but Im getting 195 compilation errors on Alamofire.

[image]

My pod:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'AlamoTest' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5'
end
```

I've tried to set "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" to "YES" but still same issues.
Any ideas?

Comment: In iOS 10 Alamofire 4.0 is used.

Comment: I've tried to change to iOS 8.0 and Alamofire 3.5 and had the same issues

Comment: @Graciano, is your cocoapods updated? If not, update it and try using pod update to get the newest version of Alamofire, which works perfectly with Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

If your target is iOS 10, you should work with the latest version of the Alamofire

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'AlamoTest' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.3'
end
```